# Theorem of Diffeomorphism.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, derivatives

I'm starting out in geometry, I dont particularly understand the notation of $df_x$.

what exactly is this linear map? a matrix?

Can someone please draw an analogy between this and basic "highschool"  differentiation?

ie polynomials?

[image]

Comment: "Highschool" differentiations has you find "tangent slopes", instead of tangent lines/planes/spaces etc. Really you have something like $f'(a)x$ as the the linear map, instead of just $f'(a)$, the number (although that can be thought of as a $1 \times 1$ matrix). You might want to look at something like Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak before going to deep into differential geometry to get your basics down.

Comment: See Michael Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds and its discussion of derivative as linear transformation.  You need to read this book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Consider the case $n = 1$, i.e., real-valued functions of one variable. If $f$ is differentiable at a point $a$, then $f'(a) = df_{a}$ isn't "really" a number but a *linear transformation* from the tangent space $T_{a} \Reals$ to the tangent space $T_{f(a)} \Reals$, namely, multiplication by $f'(a)$. (The function calculus students blithely learn to call $f'$ is in fact a *linear transformation-valued function*, or a *matrix-valued function* if we fix a coordinate system.)

Letting $\Delta x = x - a$ and $\Delta y = y - f(a)$ denote coordinates for $T_{a} \Reals$ and $T_{f(a)} \Reals$, respectively, the linear transformation $df_{a}$ acts by
$$
\Delta y = df_{a}(\Delta x) = f'(a)\, \Delta x.
$$
This equation expresses the *approximate linearity of $f$ at $a$*. Calculus students encounter this as the equation of the tangent line to the graph $y = f(x)$ at $\bigl(a, f(a)\bigr)$:
$$
y - f(a) = f'(a) (x - a),\quad\text{or}\quad y = f(a) + f'(a)(x - a).
$$

If $f$ is smooth and invertible in some interval $J$, and if $f^{-1}$ is also smooth (i.e., $f$ is a diffeomorphism from $J$ to $f(J)$), then
$$
x = (f^{-1} \circ f)(x)\quad\text{for all $x$ in $J$.}
$$
Using the chain rule to differentiate at $a$,
$$
1 = (f^{-1})'\bigl(f(a)\bigr) \cdot f'(a),
$$
or
$$
(f^{-1})'\bigl(f(a)\bigr) = \frac{1}{f'(a)} = \bigl(f'(a)\bigr)^{-1}.
$$
In particular, $df_{a} = f'(a)$ is invertible.

Comment: $\Delta y = df_{a}(\Delta x) = f'(a)\, \Delta x.$. When you write $\Delta x.$ is that a value from the $T_{f(a)} \Reals$ space?

Comment: In this setting $\Delta x$ is a coordinate in $T_{a} \Reals$, which gets acted on (i.e., multiplied by) by $df_{a}$, yielding the element $\Delta y$ of $T_{f(a)} \Reals$.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $df_x$ is intended to suggest an analogy with differential forms and the usual derivative in $\mathbb{R}^n$. To see this, first, calculate by definition what should be the differential of the "coordinate curves", i.e.,
the image under a parametrization of your manifold of the curves

$f_i: t\mapsto (u_1,u_2,\ldots, t, u_n)$ where all the $u_i$ are constant.

the differential $df_i$ is just the derivative of the function that ignores all coordinates but the $i$th, i.e., $\partial/\partial x_i$. Now ask yourself, in terms of vector spaces, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, what is the dual of the projection to the $i$th coordinate? In the notation of differential forms, this would just be the form $dx_i$. But then you also have (by the definition of the differential for manifolds) $df_i=dx_i$.

Now, work out what the coefficients of the matrix $df$ for a general function should be. You will find they are all in terms of the $\partial/\partial x_i$. The notation $df$ stresses this.

Comment: In addition, the notation of subscript $x$ is just the linear mapping $df_x$ from point $x$ in U (weird)? Also, so as a result we would have a column matrix of all the derivatives of $f$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be open in $\Bbb{R}^{n}$; let $f: A \to \Bbb{R}^{m}$; let $a \in A$. Then $f$ is said to be differentiable at $a$ iff there is some linear map $\Bbb{R}^{n} \to \Bbb{R}^{m}$, denoted by $df_{a}$, such that
$$
|x-a|^{-1}[ f(x) - f(a) - df_{a}(x-a)] \to 0 
$$
as $x \to a$;
in this case, the map $df_{a}$ is called the ("the" is due to the fact that $df_{a}$ exists only if $df_{a}$ is unique) derivative of $f$ at $a$.
The Jacobian matrix of $f$ at $a$, denoted by $Df(a)$, is defined as the matrix of $df_{a}$ with respect to the usual bases.

Hence some authors do not distinguish $df_{a}$ from $Df(a)$; confusion can very unlikely arise in most cases.

If $n=m=1$, then $Df(a)$ is naturally identified with a point of $\Bbb{R}$, which is denoted by $f'(a)$ and is called the derivative of $f$ at $a$; this is what one usually sees in elementary univariate calculus.

The above is one of the ways that explain.

If $I: \Bbb{R}^{n} \to \Bbb{R}^{m}$ is identity and if $a \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$, then $I$ is linear; hence
$$
|x-a|^{-1}[I(x) - I(a) - I(x-a)] = |x-a|^{-1}\cdot 0 = 0
$$
as $x \to a$; this argument applies to every $a \in \Bbb{R}$, so we have $dI_{a} = I$ for all $a \in \Bbb{R}^{n}$.